# Error with Rscript call, but not R IDE

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

I'm pulling some data from an SQLite database into a data frame in R.  One of the fields is a date field, which appears as a character field once pulled in R (using sqldf package):

```
dat$dt    : chr  "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" ...
```

I need to convert this back to a date.  **Converting this column to a date works fine when in Rstudio, but not when I call the file as an Rscript.**

Date conversion call:

```
dat$as_date <- as.Date(dat$run_date)
```

Shell call (Mac OSX):

```
Rscript my_file.R 'my_thing'
```

Call from Rstudio:

```
system(paste("Rscript my_file.R, 'my_thing'"))
```

Error message (same from shell or Rscript call in Rstudio):

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(dat$dt) : 
'origin' must be supplied
Calls: as.Date -> as.Date.numeric
Execution halted
```

I've tried supplying an origin and format with the same results:

```
dat$as_date <- as.Date(dat$dt, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
dat$as_date <- as.Date(dat$dt, origin="1970-01-01")
```

**Why would the as.Date() conversion work within the IDE, but not as an Rscript call and how can this be fixed?**

**Edit:**

Thanks for the input so far, below is the relevant part of script (the whole thing is ~1000 lines). It goes from the top of the file until the failure where execution stops with the as.Date() call:

my_file.R:

```
#!/usr/bin/R
suppressMessages(require(sqldf))
suppressMessages(require(dplyr))
suppressMessages(require(reshape2))

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
THING <- args[1]
sq <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="db2.sqlite3")

dat <- dbGetQuery(conn = sq, sprintf('select * from db_table where db_thing=%s', paste(shQuote(THING),collapse=",")))

dat <- filter(dat, !grepl('exclude', comment))

dat$the_date <- as.Date(dat$dt)
```

I've also edited the Rscript call, as I do include args.

Here is the data structure; no factors that I can see.

```
 'data.frame':  128 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dt: chr  "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" "2014-10-07" ...
 $ comment : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
```

The date field does behave as expected outside of R (e.g. with SQL and python).

Comment: Post the whole script. You are not giving sufficient information to diagnose the problem. The `as.Date` function is generic and the numeric and character methods have different arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one of my Rscript calls had a space in it (e.g.`Rscript my thing`), such that there was no data in the dataframe and thus, the `as.Date()` error.

I was able to simulate the error as follows (props to Dirk for the original):

```
Rscript -e 'print(as.Date(0, format="%Y-%m-%d"))'

Error in as.Date.numeric(0, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : 
'origin' must be supplied
Calls: print -> as.Date -> as.Date.numeric
Execution halted
```

For the system call, I added shQuote() within the Rscript call, which solved the problem.

```
my_thing = 'something with spaces'

system(paste("Rscript my_file.R, shQuote(my_thing)"))
```

**TLDR: The error was in the Rscript call, Dirk's advice to break the problem down into it's most simple form was excellent advice.**

Comment: Yes, when you have _numeric_ input data to `as.Date()`, then an origin is mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

One of the classic difference is that `Rscript` does *not* load the the (built-in) methods package.
So my first suggestion was to add a `library("methods")` at the top of your script.

On closer inspection, that is not it:

```
edd@max:~$ Rscript -e 'print(as.Date("2014-01-07", format="%Y-%m-%d"))'     
[1] "2014-01-07"
edd@max:~$
```

Also, you have an error indicating `as.Date.numeric` which suggests that you may gave factors in one case and not the other.  Given that we do not have your script, it is hard to say more.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I've provided a bit more detail.  I noticed the `as.Date.numeric` as well, but can't say why it's being used for what appears to be a character vector.

Comment: Dumb it down further. Retrieve some data, do `dput()` on it and simplify the script til you have no error -- or no further `library()` calls.  We can't test as we don't have your db.

Comment: Thanks, your advice helped me narrow it down and figure it out.  I posted it as an answer in case anyone encounters it.